# Replacing Tabs programmatically from Fragment and setting it to currentTab (Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-support-library, android-tabs

I'm trying to change Tabs programmatically and setting the Tab selected. In my case from **ProfileFragment** to **ImagesFragment**.

This is how I'm trying to change it, which works fine:

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager2 = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2 = fragmentManager2.beginTransaction();
            Fragment fragment2 = new ImagesFragment();
            fragmentTransaction2.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction2.hide(ProfileFragment.this);
            fragmentTransaction2.add(android.R.id.content, fragment2);
            fragmentTransaction2.commit();
```

The Problem is that the ImagesFragment View just overlaps the ProfileFragment View and the profileFragment Tab is still selected.

I'm using the android support library v4 and ActionBar.TabListener